# ip link bridge error on Ubuntu in Parallels Apple Silicon

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bridge, parallels

When trying to add bridge link I'm getting following error:

```
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
```

It is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS running on M1 Pro Mac in Parallels Win 11 Pro 22H2 64-bin ARM in WSL 1 mode.

```
wsluser@USER:~$ uname --a
Linux USER 4.4.0-22621-Microsoft #2506-Microsoft Fri Jan 01 08:00:00 PST 2016 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

How to make it work in this config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't make it work with WSL1.

The OS kernel in WSL1 is not Linux – it's an emulation of Linux done by Windows. (Sort of the same way as Wine emulates Windows on Linux.) This means 1) the only operations it supports at all are the ones that Microsoft implemented as part of the emulation, and 2) the network stack was – as far as I remember – *not isolated;* a WSL process would've seen the same network interfaces as a Win32 process did.

It appears that Microsoft never reached the step of implementing bridge interfaces for WSL1. (Perhaps because they had way too many other things that they had to implement – after all, there's a reason they gave up on WSL1 and switched to just running actual Linux in Hyper-V – and bridging wouldn't have made much sense inside WSL1 anyway due to it not having an isolated network.)

Parallels does not support nested virtualization on ARM yet, so you can't use WSL2; but it seems to me that an easier way to achieve the same thing would be to **run Ubuntu directly in Parallels**.

Comment: You have confirmed all my assumptions. Will try it directly.